# Looking for a story about a mentally-handicapped cleaning woman helped by computer

Tags: story-identification

Pre 1970s probably. A woman is perhaps very careful of cleaning a vast computer and, as I recall, it "opens windows" in her mind and she becomes normal or more than normal. I forget if in fact the woman showed herself worthy through her kindness or the computer just decided to help. One of the monumentally naïve stories about machines (when even top computers had less than a meg of a memory and used punch cards and magnetic tape.)

Comment: What length?  Short story, novelette, novella, novel?  Read where?  Anthology, pulp magazine, non-genre magazine, collection?

Comment: @DavidW what happened before i could read is an adult would give me synopses of stories they had read, so now that i cam read i am interested in finding some of them from long ago. i think it was a short story from the 1970s or before is all i can say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly "Machine Made" • (1951) • short story by J. T. McIntosh in "Out of This World 2" • anthology by Mably Owen and Amabel Williams-Ellis 1961

My notes just say: 'woman gets intellect boost from computers' and I have a vague memory that it's something like OP's question.

Comment: The title similarly rings a vague bell and the synopsis is dead on. Interesting is the year, when computers were far from widely known to most people, I think -- I do not think IBM for example was making them yet, still in the calculator biz at that time -- I would guess Univac was in the news and people had wild notions of its feeble abilities. Looking it up in Wikipedia, I am saying that it is the story I was looking for.

Comment: First publication available in the luminist archives here: http://www.luminist.org/archives/SF/NW.htm